# How can I findout the last magento update date?

Tags: magento

I want to see When magento upgrade (or update )? magento have any log files or anything to check last magento files update date ?

Comment: Just check the file modification dates on the server.

Comment: Yes its right but when I am upgrade magento with magento connect that time any log or anything saved ?  to track out the which module or files upgrade with time to date .... My client upgrade magento with magento connect but cant accept this pls help me to sort out this issue... :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Magento download page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download) and select the tab marked `Release Archives`. After each release, the date is added. With simple diffing tools you can download and diff two versions from there.